# Overlay на весь экран (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

Мне нужно сделать появляющийся при клике и исчезающий по событию оверлей 'Loading...'

```
  _insertOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    return Overlay.of(context).insert(
      OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
        final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        print(size.width);
        return Visibility(visible: _isButtonDisabled, child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
          body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('Loading'),
          ),
        ));
      }
      ),
      );
  }
```

...
При клике на кнопку:
RaisedButton
(
isScreenBlocked = true;
insertOverlay(context);
)

По нужному событию:

```
...
setState(() {
_isScreenBlocked = false; //прячем оверлей
});
```

Проблема в том что показать\спрятать оверлей в таком виде срабатывает только 1 раз. 
Как оптимальнее это сделать? Подозреваю что я что-то перемудрил. Не пойму как его добавить сразу в основной Scaffold поверх всех элементов и просто прятать показывать с помощью Visibility.

Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Показываем:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Click!"),
      onPressed: () => MyOverlay.show(context),
    );
  }
}
```

Прячем:

```
setState(() {
  MyOverlay.hide();
});
```

Overlay:

```
class MyOverlay {
  static final MyOverlay _singleton = MyOverlay._internal();
  factory MyOverlay() => _singleton;
  MyOverlay._internal();

  static OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  static OverlayState _overlayState;
  static bool _isVisible = false;

  static void show(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_isVisible) {
      _overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
      _overlayEntry = _createOverlayEntry();
      _overlayState.insert(_overlayEntry);
      _isVisible = true;
    }
  }

  static void hide() {
    if (_isVisible) {
      _overlayEntry.remove();
      _isVisible = false;
    }
  }

  static OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      return Container(
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
        color: Colors.yellow[200],
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('Loading'),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: MiT, то что нужно! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейБондарь всегда пожалуйста! Если будут вопросы, спрашивайте)